# Call variable from two concatenated strings Python

Tags: python, variables, concatenation

I have some code that generates two strings - digit_ and 'x', where x is an integer.  My gut feeling is that this is a stupid question, but I can't find an answer online.  I have variables called digit_1, digit_2 ... etc up to digit_9.  How can I call the correct one of these without using a really long if/elif function?  Is there a way of calling a variable from a concatenation of it's name?
Sam

Comment: If you find yourself doing ``something_1``, ``something_2``,... ``something_x`` you always want a list. It's a common anti-pattern. Likewise with ``something_age``, ``something_height``, etc... you want a dictionary or a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cleanest way is to put the variables into a list or a dictionary, and then access them by index or by name.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a good way to "create" variable names and access them.

However, you can just use a list, and index into it instead.

Comment: @Lattyware What are the good ways to do this? I've actually never seen this (although I fear for it being on this page, in case someone uses it in the wrong way).

Comment: Or, if they're members of a class or an object, `getattr`.

Comment: @Xymostech StevenRumbalski & abarnert beat me to it. That is the best way of doing a bad thing (normally people try to do this with ``exec()``, which is the bad way).